# Can the iPhone Location services detect whether it is stationary or moved indoors?

Tags: iphone, gps, accelerometer, core-location

I want to make an app that knows the last time the iPhone moved more than 1 meter. I can't use the motion accelerometer APIs because it also needs to detect from the background.

The answers to this question imply the CLLocationManager continually improves its guess:
[iPhone GPS Accuracy - Reading Changes eventhough Device is stationary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644265/iphone-gps-accuracy-reading-changes-eventhough-device-is-stationary)

I don't care where the phone is, just whether it has moved more than 1m. Is it possible to infer this from the location events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible since the GPS signal is not accurate to that level.

Also the indoor GPS reception is total depended on the type if building you are in.
On the first floor of a high building you will have 0 to no reception. While in a wooden shet you could have perfect reception.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

However, you have some options for indoor localization, see my [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970)